# Validation error in live table edit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a HTML table with data retrieved from database.
One of the fields of this table is updated by ajax inline editing.
Everything is all right except the input validation.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".edit_tr").click(function() {
        var ID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery("#first_" + ID).hide();
        jQuery("#first_input_" + ID).show();
    }).change(function() {
        var ID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var first = jQuery("#first_input_" + ID).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&lottery=' + first;
        jQuery("#first_" + ID).html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');

        jQuery(".editbox").each(function() {
            blottery = jQuery(this).val();

            if ((first.length > 0) && (blottery < 90))

            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/table_edit.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        jQuery("#first_" + ID).html(first);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert('Errore');
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(".editbox").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });

    jQuery(document).mouseup(function() {
        jQuery(".editbox").hide();
        jQuery(".text").show();
    });

});
```

And here is PHP code:

```
<?php 
mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_viewteamcoach = "SELECT f_player.id, f_player.playerName, f_player.playerOverall, f_player.playerPosition, f_player.playerLottery  FROM f_player ORDER BY f_player.playerOverall DESC";
$viewteamcoach = mysql_query($query_viewteamcoach, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_viewteamcoach = mysql_fetch_assoc($viewteamcoach);
$totalRows_viewteamcoach = mysql_num_rows($viewteamcoach);?>

<table class="dataTable" style="white-space: nowrap">
<tr class="title">
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="first-head">
        Nome
    </th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="head">
        Posizione
    </th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="head">
        Overall
    </th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="head">
        Lotto
    </th>
</tr>
<?php do {
    $id=$row_viewteamcoach['id'];
    $lottery=$row_viewteamcoach['playerLottery'];?>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>
    " class="edit_tr">
    <td class="table0">
<?php echo $row_viewteamcoach['playerName'];?>
    </td>
    <td class="table1">
<?php echo $row_viewteamcoach['playerPosition'];?>
    </td>
    <td class="table1">
        <span class="labelov"><?php echo $row_viewteamcoach['playerOverall']; ?>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="table1">
        <span id="first_<?php echo $id;?>" class="text"><?php echo $lottery; ?>
        </span>
        <input size="1" maxlength="2" type="text" value="<?php echo $lottery;?>" class="editbox" id="first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>
        "/><img style="cursor:pointer" src="images/inline_edit.png" width="15" height="15"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_viewteamcoach = mysql_fetch_assoc($viewteamcoach)); ?>
</table>
```

table_edit.php

```
if($_POST['id'])
{$id=mysql_escape_String($_POST['id']);
$lottery=mysql_escape_String($_POST['lottery']);
$sql = "update f_player set playerLottery='$lottery' where id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql);}
```

The problem is in the input text validation; if I insert a number above 90 the error shows up but the updating is successful all the same.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know what `scripts/table_edit.php` is returning?  The "HTML" file (it is actually a PHP file) doesn't show the query you are returning with `$row_viewteamcoach`.  Are you sure it is returning valid output?  If the query fails, what do you return?

Comment: I have added a further code to make it easier to understand

Comment: The way you have your query set-up, there is no reason for AJAX.  There are no variables unknown at the time of your original HTML.  That is why it probably always returns data.  If it works once, it will always work.  Also, you are using MYSQL, which is deprecated.  You should switch to MYSQLI or PDO, especially if you do have a variable to prevent SQL injection attacks.